# C2065: undeclared identifier, massive of structure, global

Tags: c++11

Visual Studio 2017, c++ code, point-coord of city; work_type = float or double

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#define work_type double

using namespace std;
//n <= 5 000
//-10 000 <= x, y <= 10 000
const int MAXN = 5000;
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
    point operator-(point& b) {
        point out = { x - b.x, y - b.y };
        return out;
    }
};
work_type dist(point& a, point& b) {
    return sqrt(work_type(pow((a - b).x, 2) + pow((a - b).y, 2)));
}
point points[MAXN];
int main(){...}
```

Visual Studio says that MAXN undeclared in the string. where i'm create massive of structures. I can't understand why it

Comment: [Compiles for me](https://rextester.com/GZBVD68512). To the extent there is a problem, it must lie in the code you haven't shown. Show a [mcve], as well as the exact and complete text of any error message.

Comment: ... is that question still being edited to end that last paragraph?

Comment: What do you mean by "MAXN undeclared in the string"?

Comment: What do you mean by "where i'm create massive of structures."?

Comment: Please [edit] to improve clarity.